# TypeError: in user code: While using model.fit

Tags: python, pandas, model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean-squared-error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)
```

### Errors:

```
Epoch 1/25
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-fdd9ec7ad6a5> in <module>()
     10 
     11 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean-squared-error')
---> 12 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)
     13 
     14 # Testing the model
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 808, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/dropout.py", line 96, in _get_noise_shape
        for i, value in enumerate(self.noise_shape):

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "dropout_18" (type Dropout).
    
    'int' object is not iterable
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 60, 50), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is an error in all of your `model.add(Dropout(0,2))` lines, you have a comma instead of a period. Try changing those lines to `model.add(Dropout(0.2))` and it should work.